# Rotate a Leaflet FeatureGroup with finger touch

Tags: leaflet, layers, feature-layer

I have some rectangles that I store in a leaflet FeatureGroup. Currently, if I define the FeatureGroup, it appears parallely to the screen. I would like to only rotate this FeatureGroup on top of the Leaflet map, ideally by touch commands. For example, you can touchselect that FeatureGroup and then rotate it with 2 fingers. Otherwise, rotation by a number value like a rotate-button with 360° is fine as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found this plugin: https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Transform but I wonder whether or how it works on a FeatureGroup?